# Reading a gpx file into Shiny from a dropbox account

Tags: r, shiny, dropbox, gpx

I have a Shiny app that accesses data from a dropbox account. I used the instructions at https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2/blob/master/README.md to be been able to read in csv data with no problem, i.e. using the `drop_read_csv` command from the rdrop2 package after doing the authentication step.
e.g.

```
my_data<-drop_read_csv("ProjectFolder/DataSI.csv")
```

My next problem however is that there are going to be a lot of gpx track files uploaded to the dropbox that I want the app to be able to read in. I have tried using:

```
gpx.files<-drop_search('gpx', path="ProjectFolder/gpx_files")
trk.tmp<-vector("list",dim(gpx.files)[1])
for(i in 1: dim(gpx.files)[1]){
  trk.tmp[[i]]<-readOGR(gpx.files$path[i], layer="tracks") 
}
```

But no luck. At the `readOGR` step, I get:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open data source
```

Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I hadn't specified the dropbox path properly. I have used the `drop_read_csv` code and made a `drop_readOGR` version:

```
drop_readOGR<-function(my.file, dest=tempdir()){
  localfile = paste0(dest, "/", basename(my.file))
  drop_get(my.file, local_file = localfile, overwrite = TRUE)
  readOGR(localfile, layer="tracks")
}
```

So now I can just use what I was doing before except I have changed the line in the loop to call the new function.

```
gpx.files<-drop_search('gpx', path="ProjectFolder/gpx_files")
trk.tmp<-vector("list",dim(gpx.files)[1])
for(i in 1: dim(gpx.files)[1]){
  trk.tmp[[i]]<-drop_readOGR(gpx.files$path[i]) 
}
```